# WinError 3 The system cannot find the path specified: 'Desktop\\sem_8_project\\brain\\brain_tumor_dataset'

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset

```
import splitfolders
splitfolders.ratio('Desktop/sem_8_project/brain/brain_tumor_dataset/', output="output", seed=1337, ratio=(.8, 0.1,0.1))
```

I am trying to run this code to split my image dataset into train test and val on Jupiter notebook, how can I fix this? I got the following error:

**[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Desktop\sem_8_project\brain\brain_tumor_dataset'**

Comment: It expects to find `Desktop/sem_8_project/brain/brain_tumor_dataset/` in the current working directory

Comment: I am working on Jupiter notebook, how can I fix this?